# Ant propertyselector issue

Tags: ant, properties, foreach

I am trying to extract some values from a property file using ant-contrib tasks but I keep on getting the error below. I've tried quite a few different ideas from search results but I'm still no further along.

```
xml:9: Property '${constituents}' is not defined.
```

My build file is:

```
<project name="hello" default="foo">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
<target name="foo">
    <property file="props.file"/>
    <propertyselector property="constituents" match="\bDIR1/workDir([^.]+)\b" select="\0" casesensitive="false"/>
    <foreach list="${constituents}" target="print.name" param="myparam"/>
</target>
<target name="print.name">
    <propertycopy property="key" from="${myparam}"/>
    <echo message="${key}"/>
</target>
```

My properties file is:

```
identifier=ABC

constituents="ABC_Section"
constituents="$constituents DIR1/workDir/sec1/subSec1/File1"
constituents="$constituents DIR1/workDir/sec2/File2"
constituents="$constituents DIR1/workDir/sec3/File3"
constituents="$constituents DIR1/workDir/lib"
constituents="$constituents DIR1/OTHER"
```

I am essentially trying to extract all test that begins:

```
DIR1/workDir/......
```

I'm hoping that someone will be able to give me just a pointer as to where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the [manual of propertyselector](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyselector.html):

> Selects **property names** that match a given regular expression and returns them in a delimited list

So you are doing it wrong -- it's **selecting property names, NOT values**. It should be used when you have some properties that share a pattern with the names, see the example in the manual page.

**An alternative (or, typical Ant) way to do what you want:**

```
constituents=ABC_Section,\
    DIR1/workDir/sec1/subSec1/File1,\
    DIR1/workDir/sec2/File2,\
    DIR1/workDir/sec3/File3,\
    DIR1/workDir/lib,\
    DIR1/OTHER
```

Then

```
<for list="${constituents}" param="myparam">
    <sequential>
        <if>
            <matches string="@{myparam}" pattern="^DIR1/workDir/.+" casesensitive="false" />
            <then>
                <!-- deal with your property -->
                <echo>@{myparam}</echo>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

I didn't test the regex in `matches`, you may need to fix it.